# SDL: IDE/Image Problems

Tags: c++, image, ide, sdl, bmp

I posted a question about this earlier and realized that my problem wasn't actually solved. Anyway, my question/problem is that for some reason when I run my SDL Application through the IDE, be it Code::Blocks or Visual C++ 2010 my BMP will not load. However if I run it through the File Explorer it will show the BMPs properly. I'm not sure what the problem is, maybe it is something to do with the fact that I'm running 64-bit Windows?

When I run it through Visual C++ 2010 I get the following errors:

```
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\UserNameHere\Desktop\Brain Bread\Debug\Brain Bread.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\UserNameHere\Desktop\Brain Bread\Debug\SDL.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\apphelp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\AppPatch\AcLayers.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'
'Brain Bread.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Brain Bread.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'
The program '[4992] Brain Bread.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it's because when you run your program through the IDE, the IDE sets the current working directory for the program incorrectly, so if you're using relative paths to the BMPs in your code, it won't work. Try finding out which working dir the IDE sets for your app and copy the BMPs there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the current working directory. Code::Blocks runs your application from where the `*.cbp` file is located. I am sure that Code::Blocks lets you change this somewhere.